# What credentials to use in SOAP request

Tags: email, soap

The Create Email SOAP API sample has the following snippet
      
         
            USERNAME
            PASSWORD
            2008-07-02T13:01:11Z

```
I have a IMH user & password that I use when I access the url http://imh.exacttarget.com. Do I use the same to specify the USERNAME & PASSWORD in the SOAP-ENV:Header section?  Or is there some other combination of USERNAME & PASSWORD should be used ?
```

Comment: might help to add some links, it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do.  Is the Create Email SOAP API an exact target API or a Salesforce API?

Comment: Would also be good to document what you've tried so far in your question, other wise it just seems like you're trying to get the forum to do your homework for you ...